# How can I delay a function without freezing the thread using C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to delay a Right Button click using C++,

Right now I have

```
if (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) > 0) {
delay(120);
}
```

It works fine but while it's executing the program freezes. 
Is there a way I can make it delay the click but without freezing the Program?.

Comment: use `thread` or timer in event loop?

Comment: You need to put it in a different thread

Comment: Thank you, could you give me an example?

Comment: I can't give an example I'd deem safe for you to use. While a thread may be the right way to do it, it opens up a bucketful of other things you need to watch out for, probably the most important being synchronization of data between the UI thread and the worker thread. If you can update your question with a better example of what you are doing odds are good that someone can provide an applicable example using threads or a method better suited for your problem, such as making the delay shorter, looping it, and calling a function that processes the event loop  that the UI is never delayed long.

Comment: An answer to this question largely depends and what the `delay(120);` statement is supposed to achieve, and where it is to be executed. Neither can be inferred from the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delay when an action occurs, then you should set a timer for it. Your program shouldn't just `delay` because it still needs to handle mouse events and graphics during that time. By setting a timer, the action will occur at the appropriate time without the rest of the program freezing.

Here's the microsoft guide on using timers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-timers